# shell bash, can you check if a function exists

Tags: string, bash, function, shell, grep

I am wondering if it is possible to check the existence of a function within a script. I.e. at the moment, I have a few if's to check a value and then call a function, but was wondering if it is possible to do something like:

```
if[[ ${function_name}Function exists ]]
then
.....call function etc
fi
```

where there may be a function within the script

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

```
if type Function &>/dev/null
then
   ...
fi
```

Example:

```
$ type f 2>& /dev/null && echo f exists || echo f does not exist 
f does not exist
$ f()
> {
> echo 1
> }
$ type f >& /dev/null && echo f exists || echo f does not exist 
f exists
```

What do I here?

- Here I check first if function `f` exists; it does not exist, ok.
- Then I create it.
- Then I check again, if it exists. It exists, ok.

Without additional checks you can't say directly if it is a command, or an alias, or a function; all that you known if this entity exists or don't.

If you want to run functions and only functions, you must make your check stricter:

```
type Function | grep -q '^function$' 2>/dev/null
```

In bash you can also use `declare -F function`. (Thanks to that other guy)

Comment: +1. More concisely, combine that advice into a single test: `if [[ $(type -t $funcname 2>/dev/null) == function ]]; then echo "I'm a function"; fi`

Comment: `declare -F function > /dev/null`

Comment: "There is no such operation in bash as check if a function exists" - Yes there is. See `help declare`.

Answer (score 1):

`declare -F` shows you all functions declared in Bash. From there it's a simple `declare -F my_function && echo 'function exists'`

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable method that I have found is

```
FuncName='MyFunction'
if typeset -f "${FuncName}" > /dev/null; then
  "${FuncName}"
fi
```

BTW, this approach works fine in `zsh` too.